# service not starting with windows startup

Tags: windows-7, services

I have an application which have a service that used to start normally at startup. Recently I installed AVG Internet Security 2015.Now the service is not being started and I have to do this manually. I tried to stop AVG services and make an exception for it by browsing to the **exe** file location and restart the computer but still having the same problem.

Comment: are you sure it didn't start or perhaps the process died or was killed after starting?

Comment: Have you looked for errors in the event logs?

Comment: Have you tried delayed automatic? So do you think that AVG itself is intending to stop the service?  Odd stuff, delete everything in the prefetch folder, except the readyboost folder. there will be less thrashing at startup. And yea it could have gone into non-reponding in the intital high load of stuff running. Does your service have a method of "recovery"? the tab in services to set how a fail fixes itself, and a bad workaround if you dont instead find the actual problem.

Comment: I cleared the prefetch folder and set it to automatic delay, now it is working fine, can you write it as an answer?

Comment: That was just a test, to try and discover more. Once prefetch is back in operation making the boot faster, and thrashing more stuff together , it could fail again. Wait and see how it goes after some time, and a bunch of boots, then please answer your own question with the details.  Delayed start does a good job itself of moving the service start way out of the bundle of startup things in time, soo could be that was the only thing?

Answer (score 1):

1. you can start checking on this tabs

   ```
   Run --> type: msconfig --> Services and Startup
   ```

   see if your process or program is checked
2. second try you can go to Services simply by typing "Services" on windows search see the full list of services and check if startup type is set to `Automatic` for your program

Comment: It is already checked and set to Automatic

Comment: Ok you can do a restart and than check the status of that process on left-top of the window or on the Status column